# Leaflet popup list of items and add onClick event

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

Hi guys I'm working with Leaflet and I have a problem where I want to display a list of items and I would like to add on click event listener so I can get the id, name of the list item when it is clicked :)

Here is My code so far:

```
const list = [{ id: 2, name: 'John'}, { id: 2, name: 'Bill'}, { id: 2, name: 'Ted'}];

const itemList = list.map((item) =>
                    `<tr class="is-clickable">
                                <td>${item.id}</td>
                                <td>${item.name}</td>
                            </tr>`).join('');

const popupTable = `<table class="table is-striped is-fullwidth">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Id</th>
                                  <th>User Name </th>
                                </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tbody>
                                       ${itemList}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>`;

var popup = L.popup()
             .setLatLng(e.layer.getLatLng())
             .setContent(popupTable)
             .openOn(this.map.instance)
```

Does someone know how would I add for example click handler for each `tr` tag in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all `tr` elements with the querySelector and then add a listener

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-buttons-control-button')
trs.forEach((tr)=>{
    L.DomEvent.on(tr,'click',(e)=>console.log('click'))
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering is there no other way?

Comment: What way do you want?

Comment: I was just asking Is there some other way without querSelector :D